# Force method overriding

Tags: python, django

I have an abstract django model, that contains some methods, that have to be overriden by the child class. Is there a way to make sure (by throwing otherwise an exception) that the methods have been overriden prior to actually calling the method (e.g during migration)?

```
class MissingMethodException(BaseException):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super(MissingMethodException, self).__init__(message)

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
    def start(self):
        #this will only throw an exception when called
        raise MissingMethodException("Method start is missing")
```

Comment: It is better to raise [`NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError) in this case.

Comment: It's also possible to use [`abc.ABCMeta`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta), however note https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21011